# What is the JavaScript equivalent of the following jQuery code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make spinning wheel but instead of rotating wheel i want to rotate the pointer. I have the following jQuery code snippet which rotates a pointer but I don't know how to convert this jQuery snippet into JavaScript.

**jQuery code:**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var startJP = (164) + (360 * 3);
  $('.jackpot-pointer').animate({  transform: startJP }, {
      step: function(now,fx) {
        $(this).css('-webkit-transform','rotate('+now+'deg)'); 
      },
      duration:6000
  },'linear');
});
```

i want to do something like this 
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KArr.gif

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: Are you asking how to convert the jQuery code to vanilla Javascript?

Comment: The animate method alone is too complicated to "convert".

Comment: Have you tried css amimation? and just toggle a class with pure Javascript?

Comment: yes @NickParsons

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple example, that shows how you could solve it with vanilla JS and CSS by using CSS animations which can be toggled on and off via JS.

```js
var stage = document.querySelector('#stage');
var rot = document.querySelector('#rotating');

stage.addEventListener('click', function () {
 rot.classList.toggle('animated');
});
```

```css
#stage {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #000;
}

#rotating {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 25px);
  left: calc(50% - 25px);
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #c00;
  animation: rotate linear 6s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-play-state: paused;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

#rotating.animated {
  animation-play-state: running;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    transform:  rotate(0deg) ;
  }
  100% {
    transform:  rotate(359deg) ;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="stage">
  <div id="rotating"></div>
</div>
```

Depending on which browsers you want/have to support, you might have to add vendor prefixes in the CSS code.